# Retrive the creation date of an Azure application in the Azure active direcory

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

How can I get the creation date of an application in Azure Active directory? The method of retrieval doesn't really matter (Can be the UI itself or powershell). Ideally I would like to be able to retrieve all the information possible about the applications in powershell or whatever method you suggest.

[image]

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing -Headers $headerParams -Method GET -ContentType "application/json" This is a good start, but I dont have it working yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible to retrieve the creation date of an application in AAD.

Comment: How would I be able to get the list of all applications in a particular directory similar to above picture in power shell? Is such facility available using powershell or any other means outside UI?

Comment: You can use Azure-CLI or Azure Powershell. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-install/ .You can go for the resource list option(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-azure-resource-manager/)